# query with partition and count

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Given the following table (it records users' item viewing history with session)

```
 create table view_log (
   server_time timestamp,
   device char(2),

   session_id char(10),
   uid char(7),
   item_id char(7)
 );
```

I'm trying to understand what the following code does..

```
create table coo_cs as
select
  item_id,
  session_id,
  count(distinct session_id) / (sum(count(distinct session_id)) over (partition by item_id)) cs
from view_log
group by item_id, session_id;
```

I've tried to break down the line with the `partition` to understand what it's doing but then it emits `DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions`.

I understand basic `partition` and `group by` but can't make sense of the above sql..

- edit

there's a rather large data for test...

http://pakdd2017.recobell.io/site_view_log_small.csv000.gz

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you had you supplied a small subset of input data along with the corresponding result set

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some databases do not (yet) support `count(distinct)` as a window function.  For this query, the `count(distinct)` is not necessary, because you are aggregating by the same column used for the `count(distinct)`.  Hence, `count(distinct session_id)` is 1 on each row.

Your query is essentially:

```
select item_id, session_id,
       1.0 / count(session_id) over (partition by item_id)) as cs
from view_log
group by item_id, session_id;
```

I wouldn't be surprising if you wanted the ratios at the level of `item_id`, so the intended query is:

```
select item_id, count(distinct session_id),
       count(distinct session_id) * 1.0 / sum(count(distinct session_id)) over ()) as cs
from view_log
group by item_id;
```

If so, the equivalent logic can  use a subquery:

```
select vl.*, sum(numsession) over () as cs
from (select item_id, count(distinct session_id) as numsessions
      from view_log vl
      group by item_id
     ) vl;
```

Comment: Sorry I added `server_time` column to the view_log table to signify that there could be multiple rows with same (session_id, item_id). I'm not sure if it affects your answer...

Comment: @eugene . . . Not at all.  The `count(distinct)` on a column used in the `group by` is going to return "1", unless the value is `NULL` (in which case it returns "0").

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your subquery seems to give equivalent results. Still I don't understand query's intention.. Your subquery seems to suggest that when I see `over (partition by) and group by` together, I can reason it by applying `group by` first then `partition by` next. If that's right, I don't see the point of `partition by` because it's already rolled up by `group by`.. I guess it's just too complex for my sql level..

Comment: @eugene . . . Window functions and aggregations can be quite powerful in combination.  But, you can do the aggregation first in a subquery and then do the window functions in an outer query.